# Development of TTs System using Flite

Tags: android, text-to-speech, espeak, flite

I am developing android application for illiterate people. One of the feature of this application is to read the text that application produces. So I am in need of the Text To Speech System. I found some of the Frameworks that suits me theoritically like

- Flite
- eSpeak

I even found Flite port into the Android.  [happyalu/Flite-TTS-Engine-for-Android](https://github.com/happyalu/Flite-TTS-Engine-for-Android)

The application user will not be able to understand english. My problem is now

- Which framework to use?
- How to add new languge in these frameworks?